# csv using sql server 2005 management studio without the no. of exported rows being added at the end of the csv

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, csv, export-to-csv

I want to export a csv using sql server management studio.I already know how to do so without the column names.Now I want to export without it adding the no of rows affected as shown below

```
(11094 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Already answered just differently put. http://serverfault.com/questions/168657/is-there-a-way-to-run-sqlcmd-to-get-query-output-without-showing-the-number-of-r

Answer (score 1):

just add SET NOCOUNT ON before the query to be executed and saved as csv.
Similar to below links
https://serverfault.com/questions/168657/is-there-a-way-to-run-sqlcmd-to-get-query-output-without-showing-the-number-of-r
http://database.ittoolbox.com/documents/how-to-disable-the-x-rows-affected-message-in-sql-server-18126